# implicitly and explicitly conversion of one reference type to another reference type?

Tags: c#, .net

implicit and explicit conversion of one reference  type to other reference type??
please take an example to make answer more effective.

Comment: It's not at all clear what is being asked here. I suggest you revise your question to avoid it being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of defining and using explicit and implicit casts/conversions from one class to another.

```
class Foo
{
    public static explicit operator Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.Name = foo.Name;
        return bar;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public static implicit operator Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.Name = bar.Name;
        return foo;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Bar bar = (Bar)(new Foo() { Name = "Blah" }); // explicit cast and conversion
        Foo foo = bar; // implicit cast and conversion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As has already been stated, it's *completely* unclear what you're actually asking... but it's easy to given an example of a couple of types which do this.

Here's an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit.aspx) from `string` to `XName`:

```
XName name = "foo";
```

This is declared in `XName`, like this:

```
public static implicit operator XName (string expandedName)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

And here's an [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx) from `XElement` to `string`:

```
XElement element = new XElement(name, "some content");
string value = (string) element;
```

This is declared in `XElement`, like this:

```
public static explicit operator string (XElement element)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Now, what was it you actually wanted to know?

Answer (score 2):

Implicit conversion is where you assume that the compiler or the program will convert your value for you:

```
int myInt = 123;
object myObj = myInt;
```

Explicit conversion is where you specify 'explicitly' in the code that you want it converted:

```
int myInt = 123;
object myObj = (object)myInt; //Here you specify to convert to an object
```